# es5 modular design pattern to es6

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, ecmascript-6

I have a website with 100k users/day. Currently we are writing code in Jquery/Vanilla JS using the modular design pattern. A simple js to hide/show loader is as below

```
"use strict";
var loaderHandler = (function(){
    var loader = document.getElementById('main_loader');
    return{
        showProcessLoader : function(){
            loader.style.display = 'block';
            loader.style.opacity = '0.5';
        },
        hideLoader : function(){
            loader.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
})();
docReady(function() {
    loaderHandler.hideLoader();

});
```

Whenever I want to show loader at some place I just call loaderHandler.showProcessLoader(); and loaderHandler.hideLoader(); to hide it. Similarly, I have other JS files which are written using the same design pattern and I create a single minified JS using a gulp task from all the js that is required on that page. Currently, everything works fine and I am able to call one js file function inside the other without any problem.

I have decided to move my application to the latest es6 now I have the following issues/queries

1. What is the design pattern in es6 which will be equivalent to my modular design pattern?
2. I don't intend to rewrite my existing js files but write only new js in es6. So I want the new design pattern shouldn't interfere with the existing architecture and still provide me support to write new js files in es6.
3. Also, I still should be easily able to call one js file function in other when a single minified file for a page is created.

Edit - I am already using babel to transpile my es6 code to es5 equivalent

Comment: Looks like the reason you're using the module pattern is for privacy (eg the variable loader will be private to the loaderHandler functions). ES6 actually doesn't provide any better way of doing the module pattern, so if you need strict privacy you should just keep doing what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) What is the design pattern in es6 which will be equivalent to my modular design pattern?

Design patterns aren't necessarily built into a language, they're just **techniques** that a language may or may not provide enough abstraction ability to accomplish. As it seems like you know based on question 2, any design pattern you could do before you can also do in ES6 and even vice versa. In fact, transpilers like babel take code writtin in es6 and convert it like magic to previous versions.

But what it really seems like is that you're eager to use some of the newest features available in ES6 and based on your code above it seems like you need some type of private variable and method encapsulation, which means [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) are probably perfect for you.

Converting it is pretty simple, but the only thing you have to keep in mind is that you need to export a new instance of your class as compared to using an IIFE. With a class you'll also gain the ability to make multiple instances of your class if you want to or even do some inheritance, but with your current example there might not be a good use case for those features.

In the example below the id of the element is passed into the constructor, meaning you can re-use this class for any number of elements if you choose to or  simply export a singleton instance.

```js
class AbstractLoaderHandler{
  constructor(el_id){
    this.loader = document.getElementById(el_id)
  }
  
  showProcessLoader(){
    this.loader.style.display = 'block';
    this.loader.style.opacity = '0.5';
  }
  
  hideLoader(){
    this.loader.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

let loaderHandler = new AbstractLoaderHandler('main_loader');

loaderHandler.hideLoader();
```

```html
<div id="main_loader">Hello World</div>
<button onClick="loaderHandler.showProcessLoader()">Show</button> 
<button onclick="loaderHandler.hideLoader()">Hide</button>
```

> 3) Also, I still should be easily able to call one js file function in other when a single minified file for a page is created.

Keep in mind that this has to do entirely with the way in which you're bundling your files. All you really need to do to insure this is to keep whatever you create exposed as a global variable.

Comment: "*it seems like you need some type of private variable and method encapsulation, which means classes are probably perfect for you*" - no. He is looking for ES6 modules. You should use classes *only* if you need the ability to make multiple instances, otherwise there's absolutely zero advantage. In particular, writing a class only to instantiate a singleton and export that is an antipattern.

Comment: @Bergi Except ES6 modules aren't implemented natively in any browser yet and you will need a transpiler/bundler combo to get them to work, which OP said that they did not want to interfere with their existing architecture. And as for it being an antipattern, that's opinion based because here's an article that seems to disagree with you: https://medium.com/@dmnsgn/singleton-pattern-in-es6-d2d021d150ae

Comment: Modern browsers *do* natively support ES6 modules, but even when they don't a module bundler doesn't need to interfere with the OPs existing code. Regarding the medium article, even there the author states that singletons are known to be bad, but he likes to experiment with ES6 classes.

Comment: Solid answer (except the class ref), he's edited it now - so why the down vote? +1

Comment: @Bergi A module bundler definitely would affect OP's code as he would need to begin using export and import statements in all of his previously written code. OP seems to be using grunt to simply concatenate files at this point which leaves all variables defined outside of his IIFE-based modules as globally defined whereas a bundler would properly encapsulate it. A class is simply a different way to encapsulate variables and methods and I'd say one advantage of it is that it is, in my opinion, easier to understand, but you may disagree.

Comment: i definitely disagree on that, nothing makes a once-instantiated class with methods easier to understand than simply an object literal with methods. In addition, the class's prototypical inheritance makes it less efficient.

Comment: @Bergi What do you suggest would be the right way to solve this?